# Firewalls and socket data in AS3 and python

Tags: python, actionscript-3, sockets

I'm building a service in which microphone data, recorded in a flash client is sent to a python server where it is processed. I am using a custom protocol for this and everything works beautifully.

However, in corporate networks firewalls often block the connection from the client to the server, even if it takes place on standard 'web' ports like 80 and 443.
I guess this has to do with the fact that these firewalls detect that the data does not follow the HTTP protocol.

Can I fix this?

Comment: I would recommend using web sockets instead of a custom protocol for this reason

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Google App Engine to Initiate Messages to a Device Behind Firewall](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17429928/using-google-app-engine-to-initiate-messages-to-a-device-behind-firewall)