# Using Google App Engine to Initiate Messages to a Device Behind Firewall

Tags: google-app-engine, sockets, websocket, hole-punching

I'd like to use Google App Engine to initiate http traffic to devices that will be behind firewalls/routers/NAT. These devices will be receiving commands from GAE. I could have the devices poll GAE looking for new messages, but this uses a lot of traffic. Alternately, I could try and hold open a connection permanently, but that is super expensive and bad.

The devices won't have static IP addresses. However, they will be communicating periodically with Google App Engine and the device can then listen to the port they just opened for any incoming communications.  If I understand [TCP Hole Punching](http://www.bford.info/pub/net/p2pnat/index.html) since the devices already sent traffic to GAE they will have a port assigned that translates to the port the device is listening to and Correspondingly GAE have a hole available in the firewall.

**However**, in order for GAE to send traffic to the device it needs to know the device's assigned port on its public IP. Here in lies the problem, as GAE doesn't make available the source/remote port for incoming traffic. Without knowing the port the device just used, I can't send the device anything other than http response messages. I can't actually initiate http/tcp messages to that device.

So, does anyone know of a way of getting the incoming source/remote port for GAE or know of an alternate way of initiating traffic to devices behind firewalls?

TL;DR: How on earth do you get the remote port for http messages sent to apps on GAE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the [secure data connector](https://developers.google.com/secure-data-connector/) is deprecated, your best option is to deploy a service that will proxy the incoming requests. You have a number of options like configuring your firewall and setup port forwarding or apache reverse proxy.

If your internal addresses change, then that is also the place to deal with this. For instance, you could let the DHCP server trigger a configuration change in your apache reverse proxy.

Comment: Thanks, that's kinda what I had figured. And I hadn't considered that internal addresses change, which makes the hole punching not very effective. So... I'm thinking apache (double?) proxy service for both GAE and devices on EC2 that proxies requests coming to firewall and from firewall. Said proxy service would add the remote addr+port to a header or as part of the query string so that GAE can remember where to ultimately send the proxied traffic. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

For future searchers, to follow up on koma's response here is the config for an nginx combination reverse proxy and forward proxy that should do the trick. The devices send all their traffic to it on port 80 which gets reverse proxied to App Engine. Oppositely App Engine  sends requests to the firewalled devices using the forward proxy on port 8080 so that all GAE traffic appears to come from the same IP. The remote ip and remote port are added as headers of the proxied requests.

```
worker_processes  2;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       8080;

        location / {
            resolver 8.8.8.8;
            proxy_pass http://$http_host$uri$is_args$args;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }

    server {
       listen      80;

       location / {
            proxy_pass  http://something.appspot.com;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_buffering off;
            proxy_set_header        Host            something.appspot.com;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-Port     $remote_port;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Interesting I will take a look at that when I get home.

Comment: As a heads up. I eventually gave up on the hole punching approach after having enough difficulty with network firewalls. Using a persistent connection like WebSockets works much more easily.

Comment: you mean you use websockets clients all connecting to webserver ? no peer to peer(client to client) connection?

Comment: Yeah in my case I'm using websockets clients connecting to a single websocket webserver. It looks like the websockets protocol doesn't support a direct peer to peer connection, I'm not sure if it can be done via network hole punching first, but then you're already doing custom tcp communication. Regardless, to do peer to peer communication you still need a webserver to act as a coordinator during the hole punching process.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to find documentation on the process if you have useful link please feel free to post them.

Comment: This appears to be the best source on the process - http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/papers/p2pnat.pdf and this appears to be a decent demo - https://code.google.com/p/zigzag/wiki/EasyPunch, but I never implemented it in full so I'm not entirely certain here. What application are you working on?

Comment: just in case if you are interested : http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/#simpleRTCPeerConnectionExample